# Constant network errors for Facebook request dialog on Galaxy Note

Tags: android, facebook

This new sdk (3.0) by Facebook is quick and very sleek, but on my Samsung Note and Duos continually getting network connection errors with the app. it's happening only in some devices working fine in other devices. But on my app I am now continually getting network connection errors with the app.

I jump to other apps to see if I am having an issue with my WiFi or carrier, but there's no issues anywhere else.

The problem in Facebook seems to occurs continuously, not able to get dialog at least one time out of 100 times .

Just about every time I did this, the network problem comes up. I've rebooted the phone but the problem finds its way back to me.

Anyone experiencing this? Ideas?

this is the code i am using

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("to", friendId);
params.putString("title", titleStr);
params.putString("message", message);
params.putString("notification_text", notificationText);
params.putString("data", dataStr);
params.putString("frictionless", "1");

String method = "apprequests";

dialog = new WebDialog.Builder(this, session, method, parameters)
            .setOnCompleteListener(this)
            .build();
Window dialog_window = dialog.getWindow();
dialog_window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
dialog.show();
```

Error Message : 
`reportError errorCode(-1) desc(There was a network error.)`

error getMessage There was a network error.

Comment: Are there any other errors in the LogCat?

Comment: @hichris123 no only this is the error i am getting.

Comment: You mention that it works on some devices, but I'll ask the obvious question anyway: have you added the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission?

Comment: @PaulLammertsma added , with out that permission how it works on some devices.

Comment: have you changed you hosts file on your devices?

Comment: @truenight0 no, some of the apps working fine in that device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to my question, actually it's happening when the user have more no. of friends. if user has less friends `dialog` able to load properly with out any errors. If the size of url exceeds ( it happens when it has more users) urls formation not completed properly. so this this error happening . Now i restricted the no of users in the url it's working fine..

Comment: How did you restricted number of friends? I am getting Network Error after login when looking for friends list to invite.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've added the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Possibly some devices are associating the Facebook requests with the Facebook application. It seems odd to me that this differs per device; perhaps it's related to the version of Android?

If you are invoking Facebook through an intent, another option may be launching it in a new task.

Comment: This is the basic permission in the app, i have this permission, bez i have lot of webservices in the app. with out this permission those did't work. permission was not the issue.